# What is the "correct" way of passing parameters to powershell functions

Tags: powershell

Has anyone written the "PowerShell Gotchas for VBA Coders" guide? I am attempting to teach myself Powershell, I have some experience in VBA. What is the "correct" method of defining and passing parameters to functions.

Here is my test code:

```
Function Pass-Parameters1
{param( $s1,  $s2)
write-host Pass-Parameters1 s1: $s1
Write-Host Pass-Parameters1 s2: $s2
return $s1 + $s2
}

Function Pass-Parameters2($ss1, $ss2){
Write-Host Pass-Parameters2 ss1: $ss1
Write-Host Pass-Parameters2 ss2: $ss2
return $ss1 + $ss2
}

$x = "Hello "
$y = "There!!"

$z = Pass-Parameters1 -s1 $x -s2  $y
$zz = Pass-Parameters2 $x, $y
$zzz = Pass-Parameters2 $x $y

Write-Host 1..Z = $z
write-host 1.ZZ = $zz
Write-Host 1ZZZ = $zzz
```

Here are the results:

```
Pass-Parameters1 s1: Hello 
Pass-Parameters1 s2: There!!
Pass-Parameters2 ss1: Hello  There!!
Pass-Parameters2 ss2: 
Pass-Parameters2 ss1: Hello 
Pass-Parameters2 ss2: There!!
1..Z = Hello There!!
1.ZZ = Hello  There!! 
1ZZZ = Hello There!!
```

Which is the recommended method, example 1 or example 2? I have a lot to learn about Powershell as `$zz = Pass-Parameters2 $x, $y` did not do what I expected, which is the way I would call the function in VBA. I am assuming `$z = Pass-Parameters1 -s1 $x -s2  $y` is the recommended method of calling the function as there is no ambiguity.

Any comments or suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 0):

For specifying the parameters to a function I would choose the 2 form because to me 1 is overly verbose/I'm well used to .net languages where it's `functionname(argument1,argument2)`/the majority of C-like programming languages don't have a separate line inside the function that describes the parameters, but this is personal preference

---

You can provide a name of an argument, prefixed by hyphen, and provide the arguments in any order:

```
$z = Pass-Parameters1 -s1 $x -s2 $y
$z = Pass-Parameters1 -s2 $y -s1 $x
```

You can separate the arguments with spaces and provide the arguments in order:

```
$zzz = Pass-Parameters2 $x $y
```

Either of these is correct, and most languages have positional and named arguments. The advantage to using a named argument approach is if you don't want to specify all parameters. There is also the need to consider that power shell developers can force some arguments to be positional and others as named so sometimes you'll need to specify names

For example Write-Host can take an array of things to output as it's first argument and has parameters for what to separate them with as a named argument (third, as written). If you wanted to pass the array but not specify the second arg (as written, which controls new line behavior) at all you need to `Write-Host $someArray -separator ":"` - it mixes positional and named And needs to be presented thus because of the way positional/named has been specified by (Microsoft), otherwise write will just end up being given more things to output

If you're specifying all arguments, or only need to specify eg the first 3 of a 5 argument function, use whichever is more terse but readable. If you have a (terrible) habit of naming your string variables s1, s2, s3 then calling `Add-Person -name $s1 -address $s2 -ssn $s3` keeps things readable. Or use good variable names, and `Add-Person $name $address $ssn` because it's more terse/redundant to specify parameter names when the variable does a pretty good job of describing the data. Consider using names if you're passing string literals: `Add-Person "Markus Crescent" "Lee Street" "12345"` - which is the name and which is the address (ok, its a stretch, but consider if these strings are just paths like "file to keep" and "file to delete")

---

This one turned your X and Y into an array, passed it into the first parameter and passed nothing for the second.. which Write-Host then duly printed the array contents on one line:

```
$zz = Pass-Parameters2 $x, $y
```

Answer (score 0):

Your PowerShell code looks very unusual to PowerShell users imho. Here is an example, how I would format your functions:

```
function Pass-Parameters1 {
    Param(
        $s1,
        $s2
    )
    Write-Host "Pass-Parameters1 s1: $s1"
    Write-Host "Pass-Parameters1 s2: $s2"
    return $s1 + $s2
}

function Pass-Parameters2($ss1, $ss2) {
    Write-Host "Pass-Parameters2 ss1: $ss1"
    Write-Host "Pass-Parameters2 ss2: $ss2"
    return $ss1 + $ss2
}
```

Both versions are valid. In my experience, the first method is more common, because it is more clear, if you have many parameters with type definitions, switches, mandatory tags, default values, constraints, positional info or other additional info. Check out [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7) documentation, to see how complex the definition of even one parameter can be.

You may be used to the syntax like `function Pass-Parameters2($ss1, $ss2)` from other languages, but as you will call functions in PowerShell like `Pass-Parameters2 -ss1 "String1" -ss2 "String2"` you won't stick to the also used call syntax from other languages like `Pass-Parameters2("String1", "String2")` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both Caius Jard and Thomas for your input. The vital piece of information I have discovered is `Pass-Parameters2 $x, $y` passes $x and $y as an array to the first variable in the function, whereas `Pass-Parameters2 $x $y` passes the two variables.

I need to read a few more basic tutorials on Powershell to learn the finer points of syntax and not think in VBA mode.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments that you pass into the function are added to an array called 'args'. This args[] array can be used as below:

```
    Function TestFunction(){
     # access your arguments in the args array
        Write-Host args[0]
    }

    TestFunction $param1 $param2 $param3
```

Or you can explicitly name the arguments:

```
    Function TestFunction($test1, $test2, $test3){
     # access your arguments in the args array
        Write-Host $test1
    }

TestFunction $param1 $param2 $param3
```